# ¿Cómo itero para guardar strings y crear contadores dentro de estos?

Tags: c++, string, while, get, vectores

estoy haciendo un ejercicio y trata sobre lo siguiente:

Se tienen dos personajes (un mago y un orco). Ambos se enfrentarán, por ello, tendrán asignados cada uno un nombre y ciertos puntos de ataque que ingrese el usuario. Luego, se les dará de comer ingresando "hongo" o "cake" y estos aumentarán sus puntos de ataque según se muestra:

**Mago:**
hongo: -10 puntos de ataque
cake: +5 puntos de ataque

**Orco:**
hongo: +10 puntos de ataque
cake: -5 puntos de ataque

Los alimentos "hongo" y "cake" se recibirán hasta que se ingrese la palabra "fin". El programa debe simular el incremento y decremento de los puntos de ataque de los personajes. Luego el combate del Mago versus el Orco. El personaje que tenga mayor cantidad de puntos de ataque gana el combate.

Un ejemplo de input es:

```
Gandalf #Nombre del mago
5 #Puntos de ataque del mago
Azog #Nombre del orco
2 #Puntos de ataque del orco
hongo 
cake
cake
fin #finaliza el bucle de pedir otro alimento para el mago
hongo
cake
fin #finaliza el bucle de pedir otro alimento para el orco
```

Un ejemplo de output es:

```
Los puntos de ataque del mago Gandalf es: 5
Los puntos de ataque del orco Azog es: 2
Gandalf esta comiendo Hongo y sus puntos de ataque son: -5
Gandalf esta comiendo Cake y sus puntos de ataque son: 0
Gandalf esta comiendo Cake y sus puntos de ataque son: 5
Azog esta comiendo Hongo y sus puntos de ataque son: 12
Azog esta comiendo Cake y sus puntos de ataque son: 7
*** Empieza el combate ***
Los puntos de ataque del mago Gandalf es 5
El puntos de ataque del orco Azog es: 7
El orco Azog gano el combate!!
```

Estuve probando iterar el bucle para recibir las veces que cada uno de los personajes "comía" hasta que ingrese "fin". Sin embargo me estanque y tengo esto hasta ahora. Sería de gran ayuda si me guiaran. Gracias.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string nombreMago, nombreOrco, fin="fin", alimento;
    int ataqueMago, ataqueOrco;

    getline(cin,nombreMago);
    cin >> ataqueMago;
    getline(cin,nombreOrco);
    cin >> ataqueOrco;
    
    do {
        getline(cin,alimento);
    } while (alimento != fin);
    


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La verdad es bastante raro, porque lo único que te faltaba son un par de if y la suma que es donde sospecho te quedaste estancado. Solo debes ir guardando el ataque actual (que es su ataque + lo ingresado por consola), no es necesario calcular las veces que comió

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string nombreMago, nombreOrco, alimento="fin";
    int ataqueMago, ataqueOrco;

    cout<<"\n Nombre Mago = ";
    cin >> nombreMago;
    
    cout<<"\n Ataque Mago = ";
    cin >> ataqueMago;
    
    cout<<"\n Nombre Orco = ";
    cin >> nombreOrco;
    
    cout<<"\n Ataque Orco = ";
    cin >> ataqueOrco;
    
    cout<<"\n Ingresar comida Mago\n ";
    
    //El mago come
    do 
    {
        cin >> alimento;
        if(alimento=="hongo"){
            ataqueMago+=-10;
            cout<<"\n"<<nombreMago<<" está comiendo hongo y sus puntos de ataque son: "<<ataqueMago<<"\n";
        }
        else if(alimento=="cake"){
            ataqueMago+=5;
            cout<<"\n"<<nombreMago<<" está comiendo hongo y sus puntos de ataque son: "<<ataqueMago<<"\n";
        
        }
    } while (alimento != "fin");
    

   //el orco come
   //lo mismo del mago, pero cambiando las variables correspondientes
   
   
   cout<<"\n *** Empieza el combate ***";
   cout<<"\nLos puntos de ataque del mago "<<nombreMago<<" es "<<ataqueMago;
   cout<<"\nLos puntos de ataque del orco "<<nombreOrco<<" es "<<ataqueOrco;
   
   if(ataqueOrco>ataqueMago){
       cout<<"\nEl orco "<<nombreOrco<<" gano el combate!!";
   }
   else if(ataqueOrco<ataqueMago){
       cout<<"\nEl mago "<<nombreMago<<" gano el combate!!";
   }
   else{
       cout<<"\nEMPATE!!";
   }
    return 0;
}
```